# How to add SimpleAdapter in a ListView

Tags: java, android, mysql

> I am struggling to add SimpleAdapter in a Listview with a checkbox. How do I add SimpleAdapter in a listview with a checkbox? I am currently using ArrayAdapter, how do I use this through SimpleAdapter?

This is the attempt I made below, could someone tell me where I went wrong and/or provide a possible solution?

```
                import android.app.Activity;
                import android.app.ProgressDialog;
                import android.content.Context;
                import android.content.SharedPreferences;
                import android.os.AsyncTask;
                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.widget.AdapterView;
                import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
                import android.widget.Button;
                import android.widget.ListView;
                import android.widget.Spinner;
                import android.widget.Toast;

                import org.json.JSONArray;
                import org.json.JSONException;
                import org.json.JSONObject;

                import java.io.BufferedReader;
                import java.io.IOException;
                import java.io.InputStream;
                import java.io.InputStreamReader;
                import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
                import java.net.MalformedURLException;
                import java.net.URL;
                import java.util.ArrayList;
                import java.util.Arrays;
                import java.util.HashMap;
                import java.util.List;
                import java.util.Map;

                public class main extends Activity {
                    ListView myList;
                    Button getChoice, clearAll;
                    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
                    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyUserChoice";
                    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String json_string;
                    String JSON_STRING;
                    JSONObject JO;
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    JSONArray jsonArray;
                    int count = 0;
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
                    Spinner current,new_class;
                    String cur,nc;
                    List<Map<String, String>> data4 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                    ProgressDialog pDialog;


                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        //new current().execute();
                        new current2().execute();
                        new new_class().execute();
                        current = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.current_class);
                        new_class = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.new_class);
                        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                        getChoice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getchoice);
                        clearAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearall);



                        current.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                cur = current.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                HttpWebCall(cur);
                                //data4.clear();
                                list.clear();
                                list2.clear();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });

                        new_class.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                nc = new_class.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });

                        getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){


                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                String selected = "";
                                int cntChoice = myList.getCount();

                                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                                for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
                                    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                                        selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
                                        System.out.println("Checking list while adding:" + myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                                        SaveSelections();
                                    }

                                }

                                Toast.makeText(main.this, selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }});

                        clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                ClearSelections();
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    private void SaveSelections() {
                // save the selections in the shared preference in private mode for the user

                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        String savedItems = getSavedItems();
                        prefEditor.putString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), savedItems);
                        prefEditor.commit();
                    }

                    private String getSavedItems() {
                        String savedItems = "";
                        int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            if (this.myList.isItemChecked(i)) {
                                if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                                    savedItems += "," + this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                                } else {
                                    savedItems += this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return savedItems;
                    }



                    private void ClearSelections() {
                // user has clicked clear button so uncheck all the items
                        int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            this.myList.setItemChecked(i, false);
                        }
                // also clear the saved selections
                        SaveSelections();
                    }



                    class current2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(main.this);
                        String json_url;

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            json_url = "http://192.168.1.10:8081/sms/GetClass.php";
                            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
                            pdLoading.isIndeterminate();
                            pdLoading.setIndeterminate(true);
                            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
                            pdLoading.show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                            try {
                                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                                while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()).equals("null")) ;
                                {
                                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
                                }
                                bufferedReader.close();
                                inputStream.close();
                                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                            List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
                            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                            json_string = result;
                            try {
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
                                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
                                if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {
                                    String[] s_name = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                                    for (count = 0; count < jsonArray.length(); count++) {
                                        JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                                        s_name[count] = JO.getString("Class");
                                    }
                                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(main.this, R.layout.spinner_values,s_name);
                                    current.setAdapter(adapter);
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            pdLoading.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                    class new_class extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(main.this);
                        String json_url;

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            json_url = "http://192.168.1.10:8081/sms/GetClass.php";
                            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
                            pdLoading.isIndeterminate();
                            pdLoading.setIndeterminate(true);
                            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
                            pdLoading.show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                            try {
                                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                                while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()).equals("null")) ;
                                {
                                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
                                }
                                bufferedReader.close();
                                inputStream.close();
                                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                            List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
                            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                            json_string = result;
                            try {
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
                                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
                                if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {
                                    String[] s_name = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                                    for (count = 0; count < jsonArray.length(); count++) {
                                        JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                                        s_name[count] = JO.getString("Class");
                                    }
                                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(main.this, R.layout.spinner_values,s_name);
                                    new_class.setAdapter(adapter);
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            pdLoading.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();
                    String HttpURL = "http://192.168.1.10:8081/sms/select_class.php";
                    String ParseResult;
                    String FinalJSonObject;
                    HashMap<String, String> ResultHash = new HashMap<>();

                    public void HttpWebCall(final String PreviousListViewClickedItem) {


                        class HttpWebCallFunction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                super.onPreExecute();

                                pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(main.this, "Loading Data", null, true, true);
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                //Storing Complete JSon Object into String Variable.
                                FinalJSonObject = httpResponseMsg;

                                //Parsing the Stored JSOn String to GetHttpResponse Method.
                                new GetHttpResponse(main.this).execute();

                            }

                            @Override
                            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                                ResultHash.put("Class", params[0]);

                                ParseResult = httpParse.postRequest(ResultHash, HttpURL);

                                return ParseResult;
                            }
                        }

                        HttpWebCallFunction httpWebCallFunction = new HttpWebCallFunction();

                        httpWebCallFunction.execute(PreviousListViewClickedItem);
                    }
                    private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                        public Context context;

                        public GetHttpResponse(Context context) {
                            this.context = context;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(main.this, "Loading Data", null, true, true);
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                            try {
                                if (FinalJSonObject != null) {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                                    try {

                                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonObject);

                                        JSONObject jsonObject;

                                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                            list.add(jsonObject.getString("Student_Name"));
                                            list2.add(jsonObject.getString("Student_Roll_No"));
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            pDialog.dismiss();


                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(main.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);


                            myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                            myList.setAdapter(adapter);

                            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            if(sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES)){
                                if (sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES.toString())) {

                                    String savedItems = sharedpreferences.getString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), "");
                                    selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));

                                    int count = main.this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                                        String currentItem = (String) myList.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                                        if (selectedItems.contains(currentItem)) {
                                            myList.setItemChecked(i, true);

                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Curren Item: " + currentItem,
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } else {
                                            myList.setItemChecked(i, false);
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own Adapter class inheriting from SimpleAdapter. Just override the getView method of it. and then in your activity:

```
listview.setAdapter(object_of_my_custom_adapter);
```

Sample example:

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    Context context = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = null;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data,         int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = data;
    inflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    //Do your stuff here

    return view;
}

}
```

Uses:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();  Create key value pair
hashMap.put("country", "India");
hashMap.put("flag", R.drawable.tricolor + "");
//Add it to arraylist
arrayList.add(hashMap);

String[] from = {"country", "flag"};
int[] to = {R.id.textView, R.id.imageView};

//Innitialize ur adapter class
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList, R.layout.list_view_items, from, to); 

//Setting up the adapter
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data4, R.layout.listview3switch, new String[]{"A", "B"}, new int[]{R.id.aas, R.id.bbs});
            list2.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: how can i put simple adapter

Comment: Check updated answer. You can modify as per your need!

Comment: What problem you are getting exactly. Please elaborate